# Issues when compiling CodeBlocks 13.12

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'd like to install C::B on my laptop (running under fedora 20). But it seems that C::B 13.12 doesn't exist on fedora's deposit. So I have downloaded the source code in order to compile it.

This is what I did:

1_
    ./configure

It seems to work well.

```
*************************************************
* Code::Blocks source tree has been configured. *
*************************************************

You can now build Code::Blocks by issuing 'make'.
When the build is complete, become root and install
it by issuing 'make install'.
```

2_

```
make
```

It doesn't work:

```
./src/propgrid.cpp:2391:60: error: no 'bool wxPGProperty::IsChildSelected(bool) const' member function declared in class 'wxPGProperty'
bool wxPGProperty::IsChildSelected( const bool recursive ) const
                                                            ^
./src/propgrid.cpp: In member function 'virtual void wxPropertyGrid::RefreshProperty(wxPGProperty*)':
./src/propgrid.cpp:6065:50: error: 'class wxPGProperty' has no member named 'IsChildSelected'
     if ( m_pState->DoIsPropertySelected(p) || p->IsChildSelected(true) )
                                                  ^
./src/propgrid.cpp: At global scope:
./src/propgrid.cpp:11850:96: error: no 'int wxPropertyGridState::GetColumnFullWidth(wxClientDC&, wxPGProperty*, unsigned int)' member function declared in class 'wxPropertyGridState'
int wxPropertyGridState::GetColumnFullWidth( wxClientDC &dc, wxPGProperty *p, unsigned int col )
                                                                                                ^
make[3]: *** [propgrid.lo] Erreur 1
make[3] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/src/sdk/wxpropgrid »
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/src/sdk »
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/src »
make: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
```

What's wrong ? (I have installed wxWidgets.)

----------EDIT----------

Compiling wxWidgets has solved the compilation error, but I get others when I make C::B 13.12.

This is the error:

> wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to
>   `wxStopWatch::Time() const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to
>   `wxStopWatch::Time() const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x684):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindowDC::wxWindowDC()'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x6c0): undefined reference to`
>   wxMemoryDC::Init()'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `SetEventText(wxScintillaEvent&, char const*, unsigned int)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xbbe): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::operator=(wxStringBase const&)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxColourFromSpec(wxString const&)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xc4f):
>   undefined reference to`wxColour::FromString(wchar_t const*)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&,
>   long, wxString const&)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x2979): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x299d):
>   undefined reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*,
>   unsigned int, unsigned int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x29c1): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x2aba): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x2ae2): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x2b0c): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::StyleGetFaceName(int)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x3719):
>   undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x372e): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::GetWordChars() const': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x401a):
>   undefined reference to`wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x402f): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::GetSelectedText()': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x5a4a):
>   undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x5a5f): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::GetTextRange(int, int)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x5c27):
>   undefined reference to`wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x5c3c): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::DoLoadFile(wxString const&, int)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x6332): undefined reference to
>   `wxFFile::wxFFile(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::DoSaveFile(wxString const&, int)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x65de): undefined reference to
>   `wxFFile::wxFFile(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*)'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x661f): undefined reference to`
>   wxString::mb_str(wxMBConv const&) const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::GetTag(int) const': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x7e29):
>   undefined reference to`wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x7e3e): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::GetLine(int) const': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x9099):
>   undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x90ae): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::GetWhitespaceChars() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xaa3a): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xaa4f): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::GetPunctuationChars() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xac6a): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xac7f): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::AutoCompGetCurrentText() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xb01a): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xb02f): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::MarginGetText(int) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xbbf9): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xbc0e): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::MarginGetStyles(int) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xbe89): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xbe9e): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::AnnotationGetText(int) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xc1d9): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xc1ee): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::AnnotationGetStyles(int) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xc469): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xc47e): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::GetRepresentation(wxString const&) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xdc3a): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xdc4f): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::GetProperty(wxString const&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe21c): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe231): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::GetPropertyExpanded(wxString const&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe43c): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe451): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::PropertyNames() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe73a): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe74f): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::DescribeProperty(wxString const&) const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe98c): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xe9a1): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::DescribeKeyWordSets() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xeb8a): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xeb9f): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::GetSubStyleBases() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xefaa): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xefbf): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::GetLexerLanguage() const':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf2da): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf2ef): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::GetCurLine(int*)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf501): undefined reference to
>   `wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf516): undefined
>   reference to`wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function `wxScintilla::StyleSetSpec(int, wxString const&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf67e): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf69e): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf723): undefined reference to`
>   wxString::BeforeFirst(wchar_t) const' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf740):
>   undefined reference to `wxString::AfterFirst(wchar_t) const'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf752): undefined reference to`
>   wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf866):
>   undefined reference to `wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf89e): undefined reference to`
>   wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf8d6):
>   undefined reference to `wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf90e): undefined reference to`
>   wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xf966):
>   more undefined references to `wxString::Cmp(wchar_t const*) const'
>   follow wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::StyleGetFont(int)': wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfb7a):
>   undefined reference to `wxFont::SetWeight(int)'
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfba0): undefined reference to`
>   wxFont::SetStyle(int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfbbc): undefined
>   reference to `wxFont::SetWeight(int)' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfbd4):
>   undefined reference to`wxFont::SetStyle(int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function
>   `wxScintilla::StyleSetFont(int, wxFont&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfe61): undefined reference to`
>   wxStringBase::npos' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0xfe8a): undefined
>   reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int)' wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In
>   function`wxScintilla::MarkerDefineBitmap(int, wxBitmap const&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x1135d): undefined reference to
>   `wxImage::SaveFile(wxOutputStream&, int) const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   wxScintilla::RegisterImage(int, wxBitmap const&)':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text+0x1149d): undefined reference to
>   `wxImage::SaveFile(wxOutputStream&, int) const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o): In function`
>   _GLOBAL__sub_I_wxscintilla.cpp':
>   wxscintilla.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9e9): undefined reference to
>   `wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED' wxscintilla.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa3d):
>   undefined reference to`wxEVT_COMMAND_LISTBOX_DOUBLECLICKED'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV16wxScintillaEvent[_ZTV16wxScintillaEvent]+0x18):
>   undefined reference to `wxObject::CloneRefData(wxObjectRefData const*)
>   const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x18):
>   undefined reference to`wxObject::CloneRefData(wxObjectRefData const*)
>   const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x24):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::TryValidator(wxEvent&)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x28):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindowBase::TryParent(wxEvent&)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x44):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindow::Destroy()'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x48):
>   undefined reference to`wxControl::SetLabel(wxString const&)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x4c):
>   undefined reference to `wxControl::GetLabel() const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0xa8):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindow::Enable(bool)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0xb8):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindow::SetWindowStyleFlag(long)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0xdc):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindow::AcceptsFocus() const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0xe4):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindowBase::Navigate(int)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x16c):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindow::GetTextExtent(wxString const&, int*,
>   int*, int*, int*, wxFont const*) const'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x1d8):
>   undefined reference to `wxControl::OnInternalIdle()'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x1f0):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindow::DoMoveInTabOrder(wxWindow*,
>   wxWindowBase::MoveKind)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x264):
>   undefined reference to `wxWindow::ApplyToolTip(_GtkTooltips*, wchar_t
>   const*)'
>   wxscintilla/.libs/libwxscintilla.a(wxscintilla.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11wxScintilla[_ZTV11wxScintilla]+0x274):
>   undefined reference to`wxWindow::ApplyWidgetStyle(bool)' collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [libcodeblocks.la]
>   Erreur 1 make[3] : on quitte le répertoire «
>   /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/trunk/src/sdk » make[2]:**
>    [all-recursive] Erreur 1 make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/trunk/src/sdk » make[1]:
>    **[all-recursive] Erreur 1 make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/trunk/src » make: ***
>   [all-recursive] Erreur 1

I think it comes from the fact that I haven't installed the static library:

```
[bog@Asus trunk]$ ./configure | grep wxWidgets
/home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/bog/Téléchargements/codeblocks-13.12/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.12... yes (version 3.0.1)

checking for wxWidgets static library... no <--- HERE

checking for wxWidgets platform... wxGTK
checking for wxWidgets >= 2.9.0... yes (version 3.0.1)
configure: (Re)setting libs for wxWidgets 3.0.1
[bog@Asus trunk]$
```

How can I installed it ?

Comment: (I have installed wxWidgets) Which version?

Comment: wxGtk3-3.0.1-1 and wxGTK-2.8.12, it should be enought, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

wxGTK 3.0.x definitely does have `wxPGProperty::IsChildSelected()`, so it looks like you configured C::B to use a wrong wxWidgets version. My advice would be to install any older versions you have (while you can have several wxWidgets version installed in parallel, it can result in some confusion, so why do it if you don't really need them) and reconfigure and then run make again.

Comment: How should I configure it to use wxGTK3x ?

Comment: I don't know about C::B configuration, but if wxGTK3 were the only version installed, it would be picked automatically. If you absolutely need to keep 2.8 as well, look at C::B configure help output, the answer is probably there.